# Truffle Test Issue With `address payable` and Compiler Version

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, truffle-test

I am trying to run `truffle test` on an old contract which was written using `pragma solidity 0.4.24;`. While I am able to deploy the contracts using `truffle migrate`, I get the following error when running `truffle test`:

```
Using network 'development'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
Error: CompileError: Error parsing truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol: ParsedContract.sol:4:55: ParserError: Expected ',' but got 'payable'
  function Marketplace() public pure returns (address payable) { return 0x6395927945EA39aDD6B1E04144f1e1324B30DeFC; }
                                                      ^-----^
Compilation failed. See above.
    at async.whilst.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-compile/profiler.js:369:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:969:1
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:5222:1)
    at Promise.all.then.results (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-compile/profiler.js:351:1)
    at <anonymous>
Truffle v5.0.7 (core: 5.0.7)
Node v8.12.0
```

`truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol: ParsedContract.sol:4:55` is not code I've written, nor is it part of my project. I suspect this error may be caused because Truffle *is* running solidity 0.4.24 to compile my contracts but that whatever it uses to execute internal tests is running solidity 0.5. Is there a way to verify/change this?

Here are the contents of `truffle.js` in the main directory:

```
module.exports = {
  migrations_directory: "./migrations",
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }, 
 // ... Other configs specified here, removed because irrelevant
 // to SO question ... 
 compilers: {
  solc: {
    version: "0.4.24",  
    }
  },
  solc: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 500
    }
  } 
};
```

and the contents of `truffle.js` under `/test:

```
module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // for more about customizing your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }, 
  compilers: {
  solc: {
    version: "0.4.24",  
    }
  }
};
```

I have both `.sol` and `.js` tests and neither will run (either individually or as part of running all tests with `truffle test`).

Comment: It sounds like Truffle _is_ running the old compiler, which is why it doesn't understand the new `address payable` type. I'm unclear on whether you're trying to figure out how to fix your code (use just `address`) or whether you actually want to start using a newer compiler. Could you clarify?

Comment: `version: "0.4.24"` is your problem of course. `address payable` not supported in solc 0.4.x or earlier.

Comment: Thanks @smarx @goodvibration . The issue is that `address payable` is not part of any code I've written. It seems like it's part of whatever truffle is running internally.  Therefore, when I'm running `truffle test`, it seems to use the right compiler for my contracts, but seems unable to compile whatever Truffle is using to execute tests, if that makes sense.

Comment: @goodvibration I've edited the original post to make the point above a bit clearer.

Comment: @TimBeiko your question implies that you are confident that the old code compiles properly with pragma 0.4.24, but evidence seems to be that it would not. Is it possible that this assumption is incorrect?

Comment: @ZachLysobey I was able to deploy it on both my local `ganache-cli` network and Rinkeby, using Truffle using the same setup. Not sure if there is anything else I can check?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this was a bug in Truffle. I opened [an issue on their Github](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/1817), and they have [created a PR to address it](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/pull/1820). I will update this answer after having tried the updated truffle version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need change your compiler up to `version: "0.5.0",` or newer version (but older than 0.6.0), and make all your code compatible with that compiler version, if you need to use this `DeployedAddresses.sol` dynamically generated library (see [this](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/commit/ee0a1d28f72380043f3b229541d46ff37c11f8aa#diff-26a6be586e98f27d8e6480bf44d87222))

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately this does not work, as I have some dependencies on Zeppelin contracts which use `pragma 0.4.11` and I do not want to upgrade those, for obvious security reasons. It seems like this was a bug in Truffle. They are fixing it here: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/pull/1820